# Set Dynamic UI in iOS

Tags: ios

I have just started developing apps on iOS, I would just like to know if i can set dynamic TextVIew and TextField for the app that are coming from the API/web. If it is possible please let me know with the suitable example and if iOS doesnot permit this feature, a good approach towards this task.

Comment: You can write any code you want to create any dynamic UI you need. You need to ask a much more specific question to get much more of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a WWDC 2010 session video on exactly this method. Was called something like data driven app design.

You have a server send an app XML, JSON, or a compressed plist (recommended), with all the UI object coordinates, colors, visibility, text, images, etc., then parse the data, and instantiate the apps UI from that data. Save the UI data in a local database for offline use. etc.

You are not allowed to download scripts to an App store app, but you can include lots of built-in script options from which you select at runtime the desired behavior.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this question, the WWDC 2010 session video is Session 117 - Building a Server-driven User Experience.